# Error in Java: incompatible types: LinkedList<Diff> cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, diff

Hello I need help with this error, thank you in advance for your time and consideration

In the **this.txt_absent.setText(diff);** line is where the error appears, I want to show the *diff* in a `JTextArea`

This is my code:
(It is an ActionPerformed `JButton`)

```
    private void compareActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    diff_match_patch dmp = new diff_match_patch();
   
    LinkedList <diff_match_patch.Diff> diff = dmp.diff_main(txt_guide.getText() , txt_result.getText());
    dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff); 
    
    this.txt_absent.setText(diff);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JTextArea` does not accept `LinkedList` instance in `setText` method.

You need to convert the linked list to appropriate string in any convenient way.

The simplest way can be to call `LinkedList::toString`:

```java
this.txt_absent.setText(diff.toString());
```

Or it is possible to join the elements in the linked list with `"\n"` delimiter providing that `LinkedList` implements `Iterable`:

```java
this.txt_absent.setText(String.join("\n", diff));
```

Or implement a custom method to build a string from the linked list.

Comment: It solved my problem! Thank you very much!